Efficient way to combine SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY, and a small LIMIT
My table is:
create table transactions
    transaction_id  integer  not null,
    transaction_timestamp integer  not null,
    input_index     smallint,
    output_index    smallint not null,
    from_id         integer,
    to_id           integer  not null,
    input_value     real,
    output_value    real     not null,
    constraint unique_transactions
        unique (transaction_id, from_id, to_id)
);

with the following indexes:
create index idx_transactions_from_id_block_timestamp
    on transactions (from_id asc, transaction_timestamp desc);

create index idx_transactions_to_id_block_timestamp
    on transactions (to_id asc, transaction_timestamp desc);

create index idx_transactions_transaction_id
    on transactions (transaction_id);

create index idx_transactions_block_timestamp
    on transactions (transaction_timestamp desc);

The query I ideally would want to have is-
select distinct on (transaction_id,output_index) *
from transactions
where to_id = 1000
and transaction_timestamp between 1691193600 AND 1711929600
order by transaction_timestamp desc
limit 10

Giving me the most recent 10 unique (transaction_id,output_index) pairs (don't care which from_id and input_index are selected to stay).
This straight forward way doesn't work, since postgres requires the order by to first contain the distinct on columns.
ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
doing so will reorder my rows, selecting the first 10 with the highest transaction_id, which i do not want.
Is there an efficient way to do this, using the low limit number to hopefully not have to go over the millions of rows in the table?
I have attempted the following queries, all ended up taking too long since they needed to work on the whole table, without using the small limit 10.
Query 1:
WITH RankedTransactions AS (
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id, output_index ORDER BY transaction_timestamp DESC) AS rn
        FROM transactions
        WHERE to_id = 1000
          and transaction_timestamp between 1691193600 AND 1711929600
    )
    SELECT transaction_id,
           input_index,
           output_index,
           transaction_timestamp,
           from_id,
           to_id,
           input_value,
           output_value
    FROM RankedTransactions
    WHERE rn = 1
    ORDER BY transaction_timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 10;

Query 2:
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (transaction_id, output_index) *
    FROM transactions
    WHERE to_id = 1000
    and transaction_timestamp between 1691193600 AND 1711929600
    ORDER BY transaction_id, output_index DESC
) AS latest_transactions
ORDER BY transaction_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10;


This is a circle you cannot square: you are distincting on one set of columns but sorting on another, so you need to read all of those rows in order to sort and take the first 10.  If you can take the top 10 by transaction_id, output_index then it would work.

Your last two queries don't have to go over the entire table.  They don't use the LIMIT very effectively, but still use an index on the other conditions.  Please show the plans for those queries if they are still too slow.

@jjanes I know it does use indexs to not go over everything, but it is still more than i can live with. Its somewhat frustrating simply because there is a somewhat simple limit there, and the fact that postgres doesn't use it is a shame.

What we really need from you is meta information about the expected data distribution. The output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) would go a long way. And some sample data to play with, ideally in a fiddle!

You have ORDER BY transaction_id, output_index DESC in your query, indicating you somehow want the smallest output_index per transaction_id. But that is just noise, since you effectively pick the latest row per (transaction_id, output_index) after all. Can you confirm that DESC is just distracting noise here?

This works:
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (transaction_id, output_index) *
   FROM   transactions
   WHERE  to_id = 1000
   AND    transaction_timestamp BETWEEN 1691193600 AND 1711929600
   ORDER  BY transaction_id, output_index, transaction_timestamp DESC  -- !!!
   ) AS latest_transactions
ORDER  BY transaction_timestamp DESC
LIMIT  10;

I removed the distracting DESC from output_index in the sort order.
The best query (and index) depend on how many rows (and duplicates within those) to expect per basic selection (after filtering by WHERE to_id = 1000 AND transaction_timestamp BETWEEN 1691193600 AND 1711929600).
If there are not many of either, excess rows can be filtered and this query is just fine when backed by your (existing) index on (to_id, transaction_timestamp DESC).
With a large number of qualifying rows and/or a large number of duplicates on (transaction_id, output_index), things get more complicated.
Related:

PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY
Select first row in each GROUP BY group?
Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user

Recursive query
If there are many qualifying rows, but not very many duplicates on (transaction_id, output_index) within that set, and while your LIMIT is very small (like LIMIT 10), this recursive query should be very fast.
I collect the (few!) selected combinations of (transaction_id, output_index) in an array to use that as filter going forward. Create a matching composite type for the purpose once:
CREATE TYPE trans_out AS (transaction_id integer, output_index smallint);

Then:
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (                                -- parentheses required
   SELECT t AS my_row, ARRAY[(transaction_id, output_index)::trans_out] AS selected
   FROM   transactions t
   WHERE  to_id = 1000
   AND    transaction_timestamp >= 1691193600
   AND    transaction_timestamp <= 1711929600
   ORDER  BY transaction_timestamp DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.my_row, c.selected || t.sel1
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT t AS my_row, (t.transaction_id, t.output_index)::trans_out AS sel1
      FROM   transactions t
      WHERE  t.to_id = 1000
      AND    t.transaction_timestamp >= 1691193600
      AND    t.transaction_timestamp <= (c.my_row).transaction_timestamp  -- parentheses required!
      AND   (t.transaction_id, t.output_index)::trans_out <> ALL (selected)
      ORDER  BY transaction_timestamp DESC
      LIMIT  1
      ) t
   )
SELECT (my_row).*  -- parentheses required!
FROM   cte;

This still only needs your existing index on (to_id, transaction_timestamp DESC) (where DESC does not matter).

@IdoShimshi: No, my first query definitely doesn't give you "the first 10 lowest transaction_idsi". (I briefly got confused and put the LIMIT in the wrong place, but rolled that nonsense back after a few seconds. Make sure you didn't test that broken version!) I also added an alternative for a favorable data distribution.

Your first query doesn't return the desired answer.  It returns rows with the lowest transaction_id, breaking ties using the newest timestamp but only among those with the lowest transaction_id.  But he wants the newest timestamps globally, not only the newest from among the ones with the lowest transaction_id.

@jjanes: The OP explicitly wants "the most recent 10 unique (transaction_id,output_index) pairs" The unique constraint does not allow to give "the newest timestamps globally", as we cannot output multiple copies of the same pair. My query should be correct in that it first reduces to the latest copy per (qualifying!) pair, and then selects the latest unique pairs from that set.

So the first row returned needs to be most recent globally (well, globally among the  given to_id).  The next one needs to be 2nd most recent, unless that duplicates the (transaction_id,output_index)  of the previously returned one.  And so on.  That isn't what your query does.

@jjanes: But that is exactly what either of my two queries does.

Looks correct to me. The first query is the same that I have come up with. Looking for the newest row per tuple, then only show the 10 most recent tuples. I don't understand what jjanes is complaining about. The idea to use a recursive query here under certain circumstances is also very good.

@ThorstenKettner: A misunderstanding, I assume. These matters get confusing quickly when a question isn't formulated super precisely. jjanes is a fellow Postgres contributor and a top expert in the area.

@Ido: I would be interested how the rCTE query performs for you in comparison to other variants.

What I've done in cases like this is use a cursor to read the sorted data into the client (or app server, whatever is connected to the database) incrementally and populate a hash table with the rows until it obtained the size I wanted, then close the cursor.  Of course this only works if duplicates (on the hash key) are rare enough that you obtain the target size without reading too much of the sorted data.  You could probably do this all server-side with a set-returning user-defined function if you wanted.  There is no fundamental reason this could not be implemented automatically, but I wouldn't hold my breath for someone to do that.  For one thing, it isn't obvious what SQL syntax would be used to express this desired output clearly.
Another approach I've used is to read a defined number of rows in order (say 1000), then remove the duplicates, then put them back in order again and take the first 10.  The problem is that there is no way to know that 1000 input rows is enough to lead to 10 output rows, as it is possible for the duplication rate to be very high.  So the notion that 1000 is sufficient is a matter of your judgment, not something which can be determined mechanically.
Concretely, this would be:
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (transaction_id, output_index) *
    FROM (
        select * from transactions 
        WHERE to_id = 1000 and transaction_timestamp between 1691193600 AND 1711929600 
        order by transaction_timestamp desc limit 1000
    )
    ORDER BY transaction_id, output_index DESC, transaction_timestamp desc
) AS latest_transactions
ORDER BY transaction_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10;

This should be efficient with your existing index on (to_id, transaction_timestamp DESC)

Thanks for the input, might attempt your first suggestion, but i'm surprised there is no in postgres way to do this

This is not needed ORDER BY transaction_id, output_index DESC, transaction_timestamp desc, because there is no LIMIT in that statement, (and an ORDER BY in the outer query)

@Luuk but it is needed.  Without it, the DISTINCT ON is free to return different rows than the ones you want.  (It might happen to do the right thing, but you can't be sure of that without the ORDER BY)

@Luuk If the same (transaction_id,output_index) occurs multiple times in the first 1000 rows, you need to force it to return the one of them with the greatest timestamp. Note that his original query 2 also fails on this front.

Oh, my mistake I should have read the question first, and did not notice the DISTINCT ON ...
